# Error 0x0000005D installing Windows 8 on Virtual Box

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, bios, vmware, virtualization

I'm trying to install Window 8 on a VirtualBox but when it starts I get an error message:

> You have to restart your PC

Along with the errorcode `0x0000005D`.

After searching on the internet I found out that it has something to do with Virtualization in my BIOS, but I don't have that option in my BIOS and I think don't have it at all. The weird thing is that my host OS is Windows 8.1 and it runs without errors.

So how can I run Windows 8 on my VirtualBox without Virtualization?

Comment: http://www.wintips.org/how-to-solve-error-0x0000006-when-installing-windows-8/

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error when installing the Windows 10 preview. From what I read you need to enable Data Execution Prevention in your BIOS, but as you are running Windows 8 this must already be enabled.

The setting that made things work for me was switching "Enable Nested Paging" to off. (Under System > Acceleration).

[image]